# Disproving Convergence of certain sequences in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ be the countable product of $\mathbb{R}$. Make it a topological space using the box topology. Let $\pi_{n}$ denote the usual projection maps. Show that the sequence:

$ \{ x_{n} \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$ | $\pi_{k}(x_n) = 1/n$ if $k \leq n, \pi_{k}(x_n)=0$ if $k>n \}_{n\in \mathbb{Z}_+}$

does not converged to $(0,0,\ldots)$.

I noticed that this sequence is contained in the union $\cup_{N \in \mathbb{Z}_+}A_{N}$, where $A_N = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^\omega \mid \forall k>n: \pi_{k}(x) = 0\}$. In addition, I know that a given sequence $\{x_n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$ such that each $x_n$ is in $X$, $\{x_n\}$ converges to x if for any open set $U \subset X$ containing $x$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $x_n \in U$ whenever $n>N$.I feel that the fact this sequence is contained $A_N$ will be the most important facet to solving this problem; however I can't seem to utilize it.

Answer (score 1):

No, this problem is much more closely related to the problem in [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/536243/12042); it can be solved in exactly the same way.

Comment: What's throwing me off is the $k>n$. If $k>n$, isn't the projection function mapping nothing to 0?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: No; it just says, for instance, that $$x_4=\left\langle 1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,0,0,0,0,\ldots\right\rangle\;.$$

Comment: Consider this neighborhood:

$\{(-1,0) \cup (0,1) \times (-1/n, 1/n) \} \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$

This neighborhood does not contain any elements in the sequence, correct?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: That’s not a nbhd of the zero point: the first factor excludes it. Just use $\prod_n\left(-\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$, exactly as in the other question.

Comment: But since 0 is part of the sequence now, doesn't the exact solution not apply?

Comment: @KangHoonYou: I don’t understand the question, I’m afraid; the first four terms of the sequence are $x_1=\langle 1,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$, $x_2=\left\langle 1,\frac12,0,0,0,\ldots\right\rangle$, $x_3=\left\langle 1,\frac12,\frac13,0,0,0,\ldots\right\rangle$, and the $x_4$ of my earlier comment. The zero function in $\Bbb R^\omega$ is not part of the sequence.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Brian I really understand these concepts now.

Comment: @KangHoonYou: You’re welcome.